# Converting this highcharts to my data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I would like to replicate this highcharts column graph: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/

I'm pulling my data from a table and it looks like this.

[image: Imgur]

I want the Job_Num on the x-axis where brands are in the fiddle, PercentofBudgetedHrs would be the brandsData. Now when you click a job number, it drills down to departments and shows their percentage of budgeted hrs.

I have the first part working, but I'm using different code like so: http://jsfiddle.net/98Fuq/4/

Here is what I changed in that code:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM view_percentof_budgeted WHERE PercentofBudgetedHrs < 1000 && PercentofBudgetedHrs IS NOT NULL";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jobNum[] = $row['Job_Num'];
    $jobData[$row['Job_Num']] = $row['PercentofBudgetedHrs'];
    $jobDrillData[$row['Job_Num']][] = $row;
}
```

The part I changed in the JS:

```
     var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
      categories = [<?php echo join($jobNum, ',') ?>],
      name = '% of budgeted hours',
      level = 0,
      data = [
             <?php echo join($jobData, ',') ?>,
             ];

   function setChart(name, categories, data, color, level) {
      chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
      chart.series[0].remove();


      chart.addSeries({
         name: name,
         data: data,
         level: level,
         color: color || 'red'
      });
   }
```

How do I go about doing it the way that first fiddle I posted does it? I like my method of pulling the data from a table so I don't want to use a tsv, I'm just confused on the drilldown part. I've looked at examples but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of using join() I advice to prepare correct strucutre of arrays in php, then use json_encode() including JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK flag. As a result you can get this json by $.getJSON and put in highcharts.

Comment: Okay I know how to do that but can you give me some hints as to how to use it in the example please? Can we chat?

Comment: I pointed you, what you need, I mean prepare structure of json in php, by arrays and variables to achieve correct structure.

Comment: I understand that but whats the next step after that? This is my json output. [{"name":"Job_Num","data":[5666,5667,5668,5669,5674,5675]} and {"name":"PercentofBudgetedHrs","data":[94,99,111,129,145,125]}], how I use this ?